# R: Turn timestamps into (as short as possible) integers

Tags: r, timestamp, integer, panel-data

Edit 1: I think a possible solution would be to count the number of 15-minute intervals elapsed since a starting date. If anyone has thoughts on this, please come forward. Thanks

As the title says, I am looking for a way to turn timestamps into as small as possible integers.

**Explanation of the situation:**

I am working with "panelAR". I have T>N panel-data containing different timestamps that look like this (300,000 rows in total):

```
df$timestamp[1]
[1] "2013-08-01 00:15:00 UTC"


class(df$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I am using panelAR and thus need the timestamp as an integer. I can't simply use "as.integer" because I would hit the max length for integers resulting in only NA's. This was my first try to work around this problem:

```
df$timestamp <- as.numeric(gsub("[: -]", "" , df$timestamp, perl=TRUE))

Subtract the numbers starting at te 3rd position (Because "20" is irrelevant) and stop before the 2nd last position (Because they all end at 00 seconds)
(I need shorter integers in order to not hit the max level of integers in R)

df$timestamp <- substr(df$timestamp, 3, nchar(df$timestamp)-2)

#Save as integer
df$timestamp <- as.integer(df$timestamp)

#Result

df$timestamp[1]
1308010015
```

This allows panelAR to work with it, but the numbers seem to be way too large. When I try to run a regression with it, i get the following error message:
"cannot allocate vector of size 1052.2 GB"

I am looking for a way to turn these timestamps into (as small as possible) integers in order to work with panelAR.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this big number that you get corresponds to the number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Do your time stamps have regular intervals? If it is, let's say, every 15 minutes you could divide all integers by 900, and it might help.

Another option is to pick your earliest date and subtract it from the others

```
#generate some dates:
a <- as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:00:00 UTC")
b <- as.POSIXct("2013-08-01 00:15:00 UTC")
series <- seq(a,b, by = 'min')

#calculate the difference (result are integers/seconds)
integer <- as.numeric(series - min(series))
```

If you still get memory problems, I might combine both.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think neither of these options are what I am looking for. As a clarification: I have observations ob 19 individuals that start and end at different times.

Comment: I think my Edit 1 at the top is what I actually want.

Comment: I manged to solve it thanks to your suggestion. See my own answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Tom, your data is organized in 15 min intervals, right? it didn't work, counting the number of intervals?

Comment: I managed to do exactly that, but the memory error still persists. It seems to have nothing to do with the size of the timestamp integers but rather with the number of observations. I have daily observations which decreases the number of observations and all things equal, the same regression works on that data.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the main question. Since this still results in a memory error, I think it stems from the number of observations and the way panelAR computes things. I will open a separate question for that matter.

I used

```
df$timestampnew <- as.integer(difftime(df$timestamp, "2013-01-01 00:00:00", units = "min")/15)
```

to get integers that count the number of 15-min intervals elapsed since a certain date.